# What are your favorite counter-intuitive principles or ideas within UX?

Tags: interaction-design, psychology

A quick example:

> "Paradox of Choice" - Giving a user more control via options, configuration, and settings is counter-intuitive from a UX standpoint. We **expect** users will relish their total freedom of choice when, in reality, it causes anxiety and decreases satisfaction with the outcome of the task.

I'm talking about psychological **mind-bombs** like this. I frequently cite Barry Schwartz's idea when working with developers who insist that *a simple option or two (or three)* is all that's needed to solve a problem.

It's easy to balk at this idea because we personally value the freedom of choice. Unfortunately, few people assess its negative side-effects which can directly impact UX.

**What are some of your other favorite ideas and principles like this?**

Update: found a relevant resource here http://uxmyths.com/

Comment: ...I had a very similar discussion with a developer the other day. Even though he could be considered a "super-user", when he considered an Android phone, he didn't like the multiple-step process of specifying which apps this new app would have access to... from his point of view, even though he had the ***capacity*** to make those decisions wisely, he wanted to defer those decisions to the developers of the apps...

Comment: Good/fun question!

Comment: re: the sample and android, I find that a great example: Android vs. iOS. From a bullet-point feature/spec list and user customization, Android wins hands down. And that seems like a good thing. Yet the iPhone still dominates due to the simpler (or at least perceived simpler) interface.

Comment: Cool question! :D

Comment: Arg, choosing a "best answer" is going to be tough.

Comment: This should be Community Wiki

Comment: I'm not familiar with "Community Wiki." What are you referring to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a lot of similar design misconceptions that I still encounter in many projects (coined by clients, sometimes even by usability practitioners), like:

- People can tell you what they want
- The homepage is your most important page
- Design has to be original

etc.

I've been collecting these for some time, you can find them on [UX Myths](http://uxmyths.com).

Comment: Thanks, Zoltán. I found your site a few days after posting my question and have since added your reference to the bottom. Great site.

Comment: Don't forget "above the fold". I'm constantly amazed that that silly concept hasn't died yet. (Same goes for 'no more than 7 links!')

Answer (score 13):

One I like is Steve Jobs' opinion of focus groups.

> "It's really hard to design products
>   by focus groups. A lot of times,
>   people don't know what they want until
>   you show it to them."

One would think asking users what they want would be the best way to cater to their needs but it turns out that what people think they want is rarely what they actually want. (Which helps validate user testing, IMHO...once people SEE what they asked for, they realize it doesn't mesh with what they truly need).

Comment: The generalization is, of course, "design by committee." I think that's a good one. People assume that the more minds and brains behind a problem, the better chance the resultant solution will succeed.

Comment: The Steve Jobs comment reminds me of Henry Ford quote “If I had asked people what they wanted, they would have said faster horses.”

Answer (score 10):

Users don't read instructions / web content - They just GO and DO

I unfortunately don't have any expertise in regards to whether this is intuitive or not, but I have often considered the irony in my own personal behavior (and I would argue in the majority of the population) of how **"Reading the Instructions" doesn't seem to apply in web forms, charts, graphs, etc.**

[Mike Hughes (UXMatters.com) says it this way](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2007/03/instructional-text-in-the-user-interface-some-counterintuitive-implications-of-user-behaviors.php):

> “Users skip static elements, *such as
>   instructional text*, because **they focus
>   immediately on downstream actionable
>   objects**."

We just seem to play until we figure things out... and only after we get stuck do we read the instructions...

Comment: I'd say that's universally true. Be it a web site or a new DVD player.

Comment: I came here to post exactly that. I have to remember "users don't read" to myself every time I'm working on content.

Comment: Hehe. That one feels very counter-intuitive because, as designers, we **pour** over the most minute of details. Our brains value that intro paragraph so highly! We fail to put it into perspective of the user and their task.

Comment: It's like they "owe it to us" to read the help copy we spent a week on ;)

Comment: No kidding! I don't even read my OWN content on my OWN site after I've written it up! Who cares about all that blah blah regarding my blah blah and the company's blah blah?

Comment: I think you make an important point about this theory applying to content such as instructional text.
In my experience, users do read content. They tend to scan for relevance then read around key words to find the information they're looking for. Making it easy for them to do this is crucial to creating a good user experience.
Content strategy goes hand-in-hand with usability. And just like design, creating good content depends on the objectives of the site and the target audience.

Comment: i've always liked Joel Spolsky's take on this - and the dialog box grabs on the link make the point nicely

(The point being: LESS intructional WORDS = GOOD )

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html

Answer (score 6):

*Users don't read instructions / web content - They just GO and DO*

Actually that's not quite true.

If you give a user an interface which is fairly familiar they'll just try to guess their way around it (as its 'intuitive).

If however you give them an interface which is totally unfamiliar, then they'll realise that they can't just guess their way around it - so they **have** to read the instructions / go on a training course etc.

Because they have to read the instructions / go on the course - they actually end up understanding the 'non-intuitive' interface better than the intuitive, easy to use one...

And this is all covered in this paper:

[Paradox of the Active User](http://www.winterspeak.com/columns/paradox.html)

Comment: Interesting. I can see the distinction between familiar and unfamiliar interfaces.

Comment: An interesting paper, but all the references are 15+ years old, so its relevance to modern computing is dubious, though I'm certainly not suggesting that its conclusions are false. A more recent paper would have more gravitas IMHO...

Comment: The paper's actually 22 years old (1988).

Obviously if we're talking about MS DOS, computers have changed hugely over the period.   However the interface of say Hypercard on a 1988 Mac would work in a way which is common to current interfaces (which isn't surprising given that Apple pretty well defined the current interface rules 25 years ago).

Comment: It's the same thing. The totally unfamiliar interface is the problem: after you encounter it, you seek help.

Answer (score 6):

> Users don't want to have fun, they
>   want to complete their task.

I have never found this to be true, but many people in my experience have insisted on it.

Comment: Task completion is paramount, of course, but the best systems will make the process itself enjoyable (yes, maybe even "fun").  So long as the "fun" doesn't get in the way of the goal, it's a value-add.

Comment: I agree with 50% of that statement.

Comment: I should have been more specific and said they ONLY want to complete their task. However, enjoying your task generally means you succeeded in accomplishing your goal too...otherwise its doubtful you really enjoyed it.

Answer (score 4):

> People *prefer* longer line lengths, but *read faster* with short lines

And all kinds of other behavior, where people would say they prefer one thing, but if you want to help them work better you need to actively ignore their wishes. Which still feels strange to me.

Same with the paradox of choice that DA mentioned.

Good resources for curious behavior:

- Mental Notes by Stephen Anderson (Cards that explain phenomenons like the ones mentioned here) http://www.getmentalnotes.com/
- "What makes them click"-Blog by Susan Weinschenk http://www.whatmakesthemclick.net